# Estimate parameters for a distribution based on user input

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, lognormal-distribution

***Background***

I have a server which is accessed by a different amount of the users at the same time. It is natural from the users to experience some delay in the communications based on how many people are there in the system at a certain time. Moreover, the server might run at different CPU% usage, so this fact might also contribute to an increase in delay.

I collected delay data from different number of users (10/25/50/100) on different CPU utilization conditions (70%/80%/90%/100%), as can be seen in the table below:

[image]

The distributions seem to be lognormal, with of course different `mu` and `sigma` parameters value for each different case. For every dataset, I extracted the `mu` and `sigma` values.

***What I want to do***

Given the data that I have, I would like to construct a model which could predict the amount of delay based on the number of users connected to my server, and the CPU% in use.

An example would be: *Given that 34 users are connected to my server and its CPU usage is 80%, what is the distribution of the delay? And what if the users are 73?*

***My research***

From my point of view (correct me if I am wrong) is safe to assume that since the distribution of the delay for 10, 25, 50 and 100 users is lognormal, then also the values in between these numbers follow the same distribution. From this point on, I looked at some techniques to estimate the value for `mu` and `sigma` for this distribution, but I came up with results that assume that you already have data from which to extract those values (which I only have for 10/25/50/100 users). When the users in the system are not 10/25/50/100, then since I do not have the data, I cannot extract the parameters.

It seems to me a ML problem, which I would like to explore further and resolve using either Python or Matlab. If anyone would like to help me, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The engineer in me wonders if you can't get away with a naively-interpolated lookup table.

Probably worth a shot before you sink a potentially large amount of time into a more-correct solution that may not yield many benefits in practice.

Comment: I would like to create a good model if possible, mainly for the sake of learning :)